# Replacement to HBase lookup during map for mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

During mapreduce processing, i need to lookup on hbase multiple times in one map execution. This is becoming a bottleneck as hbase is turning to be very slow.
Lookups are multiple times during one map process, example each line contains multiple employee ids, and employee information is stored on hbase.

What could be alternatives to this ? Is hbase is supposed to be slow for such processings ? Is it better to put Hbase as hdfs text and then do join instead of lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to give a perfect answer without knowing exactly what your MR job is doing, but I'd look at using [`TableInputFormatBase`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapred/TableInputFormatBase.html) (with [`MultipleInputs`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html) to read the HBase table into your mapper alongside your other data), and then join on employee ID. This may mean that you now need two MR jobs, but it could be quicker than multiple lookups, and should certainly scale better.

Comment: MR job is looking up for information on hbase, and joining with rest of data using some text matches between different information of employee. So basically Mapper gets all the employeed ids, and then lookup for the data and some processing over that.

Comment: If i have lots of employees associated with one line, then would i not end up having heap space error with doing join using tableInputFormatBase ?

Comment: Join using a Reducer.

Comment: Any good resource to help with implementing reduce side join,

Comment: @NooB8374 can you share your code please? Also are you using HDFS as source and HBase table for lookup only?